# Council Tax Rebate was sent to the wrong person

Tags: united-kingdom, england-and-wales, council-tax

I have been renting a London flat since May 2021 and I had informed the council about the move. I even contacted them later on for other issues (environmental and nuisance). When I first moved in, I was told that my first bill would take at least 6 months because it was a new built and they had to deal with paperwork.

In December 2022, I received the bill and I paid it all.

Today, I called the council to ask about the tax rebate. They informed me that it was issued/sent in April 2022. But they sent it to my landlord, which is a company. The reason was that in their system it appeared that the flat was under the company's name and not mine.

So, some points:

1. I was liable for the tax rebate as I have been living in the flat.
2. The landlord (company) received a payment that they were not supposed to receive.

Based on the above, what are my rights? I have already sent a complaint to the council and asked the landlord to send me the payment. If the landlord refuses to pay me, then as far as I am concerned, it is against the law. In addition. what can I ask the council to do as they made a mistake?

Comment: What form did the payment take? If it was a cheque, the council could cancel the one sent (which would be useless to the landlord anyway) and send you a new one.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff We are not sure if the landlord got it in his bank account or by cheque. And in the second case, we cannot trace if he cashed it out. I have informed him that he needs to send me the money.